# Python: Realtive import

Tags: python, eclipse, import

I've got the following file structure

- src

  - mrLib

    - networking

      - mrSocketManager.py
      - mrProtocol.py
  - test

    - sockettest.py

Inside sockettest.py I can import the mrSocketManager module using

```
from mrLib.networking.mrSocketManager import mrSocketManager
```

And the module mrProtocol using

```
from src.mrLib.networking import mrProtocol
```

Without the `src` it doesn't works (unresolved import).
Why does it work once with and once without `src`?

Comment: What is your `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: Do you have another `mrLib` folder lying around. Do you have `__init__.py` in all your subfolders? If so what is the content of each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `PYTHONPATH` environment variable - it describes root of your packages structure. Add src/ directory to it.

Comment: I am using Eclipse and the src folder is already in PYTHONPATH.

Comment: That was the problem. I used subfolder of src inside eclipse to solve the problems